# Errores Web Service Java Web - EclipseLink

Tags: java, webservice, java-ee

He creado un Web Service, pero me salen varios errores, al momento de dar clic en Test Web Service sale

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.plugins.BeanValidationPlugin Unable to get public no-arg constructor
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:673)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1232)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:1267)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:1266)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1269)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1383)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.findServices(Options.java:957)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.getAllPlugins(Options.java:374)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.<init>(AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.java:100)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.ExtensionBindingChecker.<init>(ExtensionBindingChecker.java:81)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader$XMLSchemaParser.parse(ModelLoader.java:264)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:347)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.parse(ParserContext.java:128)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.<init>(ParserContext.java:100)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.<init>(XSOMParser.java:113)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOMParser(ModelLoader.java:437)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOMParser(ModelLoader.java:445)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:527)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:269)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:142)
at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2298)
at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:198)
at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:141)
at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:444)
at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:205)
at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:183)
at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport2.runInVm(WsImport2.java:575)
at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsTask2.execute(WsTask2.java:423)
at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport2.execute(WsImport2.java:558)
at com.sun.istack.tools.ProtectedTask.execute(ProtectedTask.java:103)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor160.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1391)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1254)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:261)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:573)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.doRun(RunClassThread.java:132)
at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:81)Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/xjc/model/CPropertyVisitor2
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3305)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3510)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2238)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:660)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:657)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:668)
... 50 moreCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.xjc.model.CPropertyVisitor2
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1383)
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1338)
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1093)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
... 58 more BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Web Service ArchivoWS

```
package ArchivoWeb;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Stateless

@WebService(serviceName = "ArchivoWS")
public class ArchivoWS {

    ClienteJpaController ayuda;
    UserTransaction usuario;
    Cliente cliente = null;
    @Resource(name = "sessionContext")
    SessionContext contexto;

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "registro")
    public String registro(@WebParam(name = "ced") long ced) {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            contexto = (SessionContext) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/sessionContext");
            usuario = contexto.getUserTransaction();
        } catch (NamingException | IllegalStateException e) {
        }
        EntityManagerFactory factoria;
        factoria = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ArchivoWebPU");
        ayuda = new ClienteJpaController(usuario, factoria);
        cliente = ayuda.findCliente(ced);
        if (cliente == null) {
            return "No Existe cedula";
        } else {
            String cadena = " ";
            cadena = cadena + "Cedula:" + cliente.getIdcliente() + "\n";
            cadena = cadena + "Nombre:" + cliente.getNomcliente() + "\n";
            cadena = cadena + "Domicilio:" + cliente.getDomcliente() + "\n";
            cadena = cadena + "Telefono:" + cliente.getTelcliente() + "\n";
            return cadena;
        }
    }
}
```

Puedo agregar operaciones sin problema, pero no se muestran

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y sale este error

```
    java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl (in unnamed module @0x1ae3c12f) cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl (in module java.xml) because module java.xml does not export com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom to unnamed module @0x1ae3c12f
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.<init>(SOAPPartImpl.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.<init>(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl.getSOAPPart(Message1_1Impl.java:90)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.design.javamodel.Utils.setSoapRequest(Utils.java:558)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.design.javamodel.Utils.populateOperation(Utils.java:497)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.design.javamodel.Utils.access$100(Utils.java:109)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.design.javamodel.Utils$1.run(Utils.java:352)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.design.javamodel.Utils$1.run(Utils.java:173)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.JavaSource$MultiTask.run(JavaSource.java:502)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callUserTask(TaskProcessor.java:586)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager$UserTaskAction.run(ParserManager.java:130)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager$UserTaskAction.run(ParserManager.java:114)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$2.call(TaskProcessor.java:181)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$2.call(TaskProcessor.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.utils.FileChangedManager.priorityIO(FileChangedManager.java:153)
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.providers.ProvidedExtensions.priorityIO(ProvidedExtensions.java:335)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.nb.DataObjectEnvFactory.runPriorityIO(DataObjectEnvFactory.java:118)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.Utilities.runPriorityIO(Utilities.java:67)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.runUserTask(TaskProcessor.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.RunWhenScanFinishedSupport.runWhenScanFinished(RunWhenScanFinishedSupport.java:123)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager.parseWhenScanFinished(ParserManager.java:107)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.JavaSource.runWhenScanFinished(JavaSource.java:628)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.design.javamodel.Utils.populateModel(Utils.java:366)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.design.javamodel.ServiceModel.populateModel(ServiceModel.java:360)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.design.javamodel.ServiceModel.<init>(ServiceModel.java:76)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.design.javamodel.ServiceModel.getServiceModel(ServiceModel.java:83)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.design.view.DesignView$3.doInBackground(DesignView.java:231)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.design.view.DesignView$3.doInBackground(DesignView.java:227)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:343)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.get(SwingWorker.java:613)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.design.view.DesignView$3.done(DesignView.java:242)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(SwingWorker.java:750)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(SwingWorker.java:847)
    at java.desktop/sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(AccumulativeRunnable.java:112)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(SwingWorker.java:857)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:310)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:242)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:136)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```